# 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, branding

I am new to sharepoint and was creating a sample program for my learning and after executing it when i tried to open my sharepoint site it gives me following error:

401 UNAUTHORIZED

This is how it happened:

I was creating a feature receiver and on it the code was written to change the master page as:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite _site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {
                using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SetMasterPage(_web, "v4CopySPLearning.master");
                }
            }
        );          
    }

    private void SetMasterPage(SPWeb _web, string _masterPage)
    {
        var masterUri = new Uri(_web.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + _masterPage);
        _web.MasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
        _web.CustomMasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
        _web.Update();
    }
```

this "v4CopySPLearning.master" is my custom master page which is nothing but the copy + paste of v4.master and was placed at:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL

Then I deployed this project and when i opened my sharepoint site it gives me 401 UNAUTHORIZED error.

Then i retracted my sharepoint solution but it didn't worked and gave me same
401 UNAUTHORIZED
error.

Then i browsed internet and found poweshell script to deploy default master page as:
$web = Get-SPWeb 
$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master"
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()

It got executed without error but the
401 UNAUTHORIZED error still persists.

Any solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a backup? I would restore in CA(central administration). Otherwise apply the default master page to your site for the meantime(so there is something to work with) and research your idea before implementing it. I use a pseudo subsite as my practice environment

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have code in front of me that I am using to update the master pages in a feature activation event receiver, it looks like this:

```
var site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
var web = site.RootWeb;

var rootUrl = web.Url;
var customMasterUrl = new Uri(rootUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/cusom.master");
var systemMasterUrl = new Uri(rootUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/v4_custom.master");
//Site Master Page 
web.CustomMasterUrl = customMasterUrl.AbsolutePath;
//System Master Page 
web.MasterUrl = systemMasterUrl.AbsolutePath;
web.Update();
```

I've used this method in several features to set custom master pages without issue.